# Why the image's data has changed by calling UIImageJPEGRepresentation in iOS

Tags: ios, encode

Here is an images.jpg which is only 3,198 bytes, after calling `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` like this:

[image]

It's data size is 15,422 bytes.

Why is it? I want to know, the `imageData` is using which encoding form? UTF-8 or UTF-16 or others? And, maybe the original data is using unicode? I'm not sure, help me, thanks!!!

Update:

Thanks to @Fonix!

But what about the PNG? There are just one parameter in `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, and I found a png which is 2.9M will be compressed to 62K after call the png's method. So, If I want to get the `SAME` data, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a value less than 1 in `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` because this determines the compression quality, so you are probably taking a compressed jpg, and basically making it uncompressed. [some documention](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation)

try reading in the image data using this method

```
NSURL *imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"imageName" withExtension:@"png"];
NSString*stringPath = [imgPath absoluteString]; 

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringPath]];
```

Comment: maximum value of compression quality is 1.

Comment: other way round: "The quality of the resulting JPEG image, expressed as a value from 0.0 to 1.0. The value 0.0 represents the maximum compression (or lowest quality) while the value 1.0 represents the least compression (or best quality)."

Comment: Thanks, you are right! But what about the `PNG`? There are just one parameter in `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, and I found a png which is 2.9M will be compressed to 62K.  So, If I want to get the `SAME` data, what should I do?

Comment: i think you need to read about how jpgs and png's work :P what are you trying to do though? once your image is a UIImage, you are at the mercy of iOS on how the data is given back to you, which may not be exactly the same (but probably close enough for png because png is lossless) you are better off just reading in the image file manually and copying the data out if you need the exact data

Comment: png only has 1 parameter because there are no levels of compression with png, if your jpeg has very solid colours in it, png will compress it well, which could be why you get such a vastly different file size

Comment: @Fonix , Yes! That's what I need!  Thanks very much.